# Windows Workflow - Use on eCommerce Site?

Tags: workflow-foundation

I've been doing some tutorials, and a lot of reading on Windows Workflow recently, and was just wondering if it would be practical to use it in an eCommerce website - at the check out for example...?

Customer Checks basket
customer enters delivery information
customer checks order
customer pays
*done*

or am i barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rob Conery did something similar in [one of his ASP.NET MVC Storefront tutorials](http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/mvcstore-part-19/).

Is it possible, absolutely.

Would you actually want to use WF to do this sort of thing. I wouldn't advise any of my clients to do this for two reasons:

1. In most cases the cost of instantiating and loading WF is overkill for the task being accomplished. A simple state machine implementation will suffice in most cases.
2. The current version of WF is end-of-lifetime. Microsoft has already announced that there will be significant breaking changes in the next release of WF. I feel like WF is at the wrong end of the $$$ versus value added equation at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would be a practical use.

However, Microsofts Commerce Server uses a pipeline technology.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd451186.aspx